# Allow user to add dot to image

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a fairly simple question that I can't seem to get working. I'm trying to make it so that a user can upload an image to my program, and wherever they click on the image, a red dot and associated text label will appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have refactored the code and can now get the dots and label to appear, but it's appearing to the right of the image instead of directly on top of the image where the user clicks. Any insight into how I could fix that? Thanks again!

```
const Coordinates = () => {
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ x1: "", x2: "", y1: "", y2: "", mode: "linear"  });
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
  const [dots, setDots] = useState([]);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  const handleInputChange = (field, value) => {
    setCoordinates({
      ...coordinates,
      [field]: value
    });
  };

  const handleEdit = (field) => {
    setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => ({ ...prevCoordinates, [field]: '' }));
    setClickCount(0);
  };

 const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
   const bounds = imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - bounds.left;
  const y = event.clientY - bounds.top;
  setMousePosition({ x, y });
  };

 const handleClick = (event) => {
    const bounds = imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - bounds.left;
    const y = event.clientY - bounds.top;
    const newDot = { x, y };

    setDots(prevDots => [...prevDots, newDot]);

    const formattedPosition = `(${x}, ${y})`;
    switch(dots.length) {
      case 0:
        handleInputChange('x1', formattedPosition);
        break;
      case 1:
        handleInputChange('x2', formattedPosition);
        break;
      case 2:
        handleInputChange('y1', formattedPosition);
        break;
      case 3:
        handleInputChange('y2', formattedPosition);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

 const handleFileInputChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  };

 const clearFields = () => {
    setCoordinates({
      x1: "",
      x2: "",
      y1: "",
      y2: "",
      new1: "",
      new2: "",
      new3: "",
      new4: "",
      mode: coordinates.mode
    });

    setClickCount(0);
  };

  const handleDropdownChange = (event) => {
    setCoordinates({
      ...coordinates,
      mode: event.target.value
    });
  };

 return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="file-upload">
        <label htmlFor="file-input">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" onChange={handleFileInputChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="image-container" ref={imageRef}>
        {imageUrl && (
          <img ref={imageRef} src={imageUrl} alt="uploaded" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onClick={handleClick} />
        )}
        {dots.map((dot, index) => {
          const labels = ['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2'];
          return (
            <div key={index} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
              <div className="dot" style={{ left: dot.x, top: dot.y }}></div>
              {labels[index] && (
                <span className="dot-label" style={{ left: dot.x + 15, top: dot.y }}>{labels[index]}</span>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="coords-container">
        <p className="coords">X: {mousePosition.x}</p>
        <p className="coords2">Y: {mousePosition.y}</p>
      </div>
      <Grid coordinates={coordinates} handleInputChange={handleInputChange} handleEdit={handleEdit} />
    </div>
  );

 };

export default Coordinates;
```

My CSS for the dots is the following:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.empty-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.coords-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.coords {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.coords2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.text-box-container button {
  margin-left: 5px;
};

.input-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-container label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.input-container input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}


.input-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
   grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-container label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.input-container input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.clear-button-container {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.edit-button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dot-label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 15px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: You want, but you do not show your work on how YOU tried to solve your issue? What exact errors you got? How did you approach them? SO is not a code writing service! Please take the [tour]. See also [ask] and in your Question add a [mre]

Comment: @Ron, I've fixed it up so that I can now at least render the dots and label to the screen, but it appears to the right of the uploaded image instead of directly on top of it, where the user clicks. I think it might be related to how my CSS is rendering it, so I have included that code as well. Any insight would be appreciated!